# Triangle Bisector

Tags: geometry, triangles

$\overline{BE}$ and $\overline{CF}$ are angle bisectors of $\triangle ABC$ that meet at $I$, and we have $CE = 4$, $AE = 6$, and $AB = 8$. Find $BF$.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Hve you tried to apply the bisector theorem? $\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{AB}{BC}$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Jack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the hint given in the comments, the bisector theorem gives
$$\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{AB}{BC},$$
hence in our case $BC=\frac{16}{3}$. By the bisector theorem again,
$$ BF = \frac{BC}{BC+CA}\cdot AB = \frac{\frac{16}{3}}{\frac{16}{3}+10}\cdot 8 =\color{red}{\frac{64}{23}}.$$

[image]